# Find DOY corresponding to a given percentile

Tags: r, percentile

I have a dataframe with daily NDVI values from 2013 to 2017.
My dataframe has continuous NDVI data (i.e., for every day of the year) but here is a reproducible example of the structure of my dataframe:

```
year <- sample(2013:2017, 750,replace=TRUE)
DOY <- sample(1:365, 750,replace=TRUE)
NDVI<- runif(750, -1, 1)
df <- cbind(year,DOY,NDVI)
```

I use the quantile and tapply functions to find, for each year in the dataframe, the NDVI value corresponding to the 10th, 30th, 50th, and 80th percentile:

```
quantile=do.call("rbind", tapply(df$NDVI, df$year, quantile,c(0.10, 0.30, 0.50, 0.80)))
```

My question is: how can I find the DOY corresponding to the 10th, 30th, 50th, 80th percentile of NDVI values for every year? For example, if a NDVI value of 0.3 corresponds to the 50th percentile of 2014, I would like to return the DOY corresponding to a NDVI of 0.3.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar solutions to that from Len, and I reiterate what they say about the difficulties of making an exact match. I've used the same seed to make the results comparable. The difference is I keep the quantiles in long form which makes the filtering step easier.

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(1)
year <- sample(2013:2017, 750,replace=TRUE)
DOY <- sample(1:365, 750,replace=TRUE)
NDVI<- runif(750, -1, 1)
df <- data_frame(year,DOY,NDVI)

df %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  do(data_frame(p = c(10, 30, 50, 80)/100, q = quantile(.$NDVI, probs = p))) %>% 
  full_join(df) %>% 
  group_by(year, p) %>% 
  slice(which.min(abs(NDVI - q)))


# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   year, p [20]
    year     p        q   DOY     NDVI
   <int> <dbl>    <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1  2013 0.100 -0.844     247 -0.844  
 2  2013 0.300 -0.459      96 -0.447  
 3  2013 0.500 -0.0144    202 -0.0144 
 4  2013 0.800  0.583      59  0.584  
 5  2014 0.100 -0.811     128 -0.818  
 6  2014 0.300 -0.403      37 -0.410  
 7  2014 0.500 -0.0136    187 -0.0136 
 8  2014 0.800  0.623     278  0.620  
 9  2015 0.100 -0.890     280 -0.887  
10  2015 0.300 -0.494     330 -0.488  
11  2015 0.500 -0.0332    316 -0.0332 
12  2015 0.800  0.646     190  0.647  
13  2016 0.100 -0.803     351 -0.803  
14  2016 0.300 -0.447     206 -0.447  
15  2016 0.500 -0.00170   122 -0.00170
16  2016 0.800  0.548     353  0.548  
17  2017 0.100 -0.824     326 -0.830  
18  2017 0.300 -0.484     124 -0.483  
19  2017 0.500 -0.00704   175 -0.00900
20  2017 0.800  0.573      95  0.570
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this to have my solution in tidy format as well, but could not come up with it this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, sometimes a percentile does not match a true observation in NDVI. In those cases the mean is takes of the NDVI values around for example the 30th percentile for year X. In those cases I took the two values of NDVI that are closest to that of the 30th percentile, you can choose to pick both or take the mean of the corresponding DOY values as well. Perhaps it is a little workaround, but this was the best I could come up with now:

```
set.seed(1)
year <- sample(2013:2017, 750,replace=TRUE)
DOY <- sample(1:365, 750,replace=TRUE)
NDVI<- runif(750, -1, 1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(year,DOY,NDVI))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  do( tidy(t(quantile(.$NDVI, c(0.10, 0.30, 0.50, 0.80)))) ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  right_join(df) %>% 
  arrange(year, NDVI) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(abs(X10. - NDVI) == min(abs(X10. - NDVI)) |
       abs(X30. - NDVI) == min(abs(X30. - NDVI)) |
       abs(X50. - NDVI) == min(abs(X50. - NDVI))|
       abs(X80. - NDVI) == min(abs(X80. - NDVI)))
```

Which gives:

```
    year   X10.   X30.    X50.  X80.   DOY    NDVI
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2013. -0.844 -0.459 -0.0144 0.583  247. -0.844 
 2 2013. -0.844 -0.459 -0.0144 0.583   96. -0.447 
 3 2013. -0.844 -0.459 -0.0144 0.583  202. -0.0144
 4 2013. -0.844 -0.459 -0.0144 0.583   59.  0.584 
 5 2014. -0.811 -0.403 -0.0136 0.623  128. -0.818 
 6 2014. -0.811 -0.403 -0.0136 0.623   37. -0.410 
 7 2014. -0.811 -0.403 -0.0136 0.623  187. -0.0136
 8 2014. -0.811 -0.403 -0.0136 0.623  278.  0.620 
 9 2015. -0.890 -0.494 -0.0332 0.646  280. -0.887 
10 2015. -0.890 -0.494 -0.0332 0.646  330. -0.488
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very helpful!